# Logic of Defining a Function inside another Function Python

Tags: python, loops, break

I am trying to write a function that returns all of the possible k-mers with a maximum Hamming distance of d from each of the input DNA strings. 
My original attempt was to just try straight forward iteration.

```
def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    pattern = []
    c = 0
    combos = combination(k)
    for combo in combos:
        for strings in DNA:
            while c+k < len(DNA[0])-1:
                if d >= hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]):
                    #move onto next string 
                elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]) and c+k == len(DNA[0])-1:
                    #if the combo wasn't valid for a string, move onto the next combo
                    break
                elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]):
                    #change the window to see if the combo is valid later in the string 
                    c += 1
        pattern+=[combo]   
    return pattern
```

Unfortunately, I learned that I can't make a continue statement for an outer loop, and I read that the best way to approach this is to define a function inside my loop and then call it. This is very confusing to me, but here is my attempt at that approach:

```
def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    combos = combination(k)
    global pattern
    global c
    for combo in combos:
        def inner(string, combo, count):
            global pattern
            global DNA
            global c
            if count==len(DNA):
                pattern += [combo]
                return pattern
            while c+k <= len(DNA[0])-1:
                if d >= hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]):
                    #move onto next string 
                        count+=1
                        c = 0
                        string = DNA[count]
                        return inner(string, combo, count)
                elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]) and c+k == len(DNA[0])-1:
                    #if the combo wasn't valid for a string, the inner function loop breaks
                    break
                elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]):
                    #change the window to see if the combo is valid later in the string 
                    c += 1
        inner(DNA[0], combo, count = 0)
    return pattern
```

My logic was that my inner function would iterate through all of strings in my list DNA, and if the hamming distance was less than or equal to d, it would keep calling itself with a new element of DNA in mind. Then, if the condition was satisfied for all of them, hence count==len(DNA), then the pattern would be updated and returned (since it is a global variable, I wouldn't need to return the inner function, just call it). 
This, however, does not return anything. Any suggested readings or just straight up suggestions to help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *literally* define one method in another. You only need to call the inner method in the first method. This way to move to the next iteration in the outer loop you can call `return` in `inner_loop`

```
def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    pattern = []
    c = 0
    combos = combination(k)
    for combo in combos:
        inner_loop(k,d,DNA,combo, c)
    return pattern

def inner_loop(k, d, DNA, combo, c):
    for strings in DNA:
        inner_loop_two(k, d, DNA, combo, c)
```

### Edit

To implement the `##move onto next string` code, you can use *another* inner function.

You can split `inner_loop` like so:

```
def inner_loop(k, d, DNA, combo, c):
    for strings in DNA:
        inner_loop_two(k, d, DNA, combo, c)

def inner_loop_two(k, d, DNA, combo, c):
    while c+k < len(DNA[0])-1:
        if d >= hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]):
            #move onto next string 
            continue
        elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]) and c+k == len(DNA[0])-1:
            #if the combo wasn't valid for a string, move onto the next combo
            break
        elif d < hammingDistance(combo, string[c:c+k]):
            #change the window to see if the combo is valid later in the string 
            c += 1
    pattern+=[combo]
```

Comment: How can I get the "move onto next string" into my code?